# Understand tmpfs size

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, tmpfs

I need to use a tmpfs on linux. I have some files to play with, I know how many files I have, and I know the size of each file.
How can I decide the size of my tmpfs ?

I'm using mount program : `mount -t tmpfs -o size=?? name_tmpfs /mnt/mountpoint_tmpfs`

I'm trying to understand what value to use for the size.
I did a test, by creating a tmpfs of 4096 (page size) bytes, I created a file in it but if I want to fill it (with just one byte per example) I have an "error writing on swap" ... I do not understand how much size I need to store a 1 byte file, so for my "work files" I'm totally lost !

Every tutorial I found uses a random big size for their examples, but I really want to understand the mechanism and understand how much tmpfs size I need for my work files (I know how many, and each size, I can find a solution right ?).

Thank you for reading :)

Answer (score 1):

A file system contains data and metadata. Metadata is usually fixed in size, and allocated during fs creation (`nr_inodes` tmpfs mount option). Data also occupy fixed size chunks, regardless of actual file size. To see the actual data usage, `du -s` will do a great job:

```
root@localhost:/run/shm# echo > x; du -sh x
4.0K    x
```

As you can see, on my kernel, tmpfs is using 4096 byte chunks to store files, so every file's size will be rounded up to 4096 or multiplies of it. I created a tmpfs with a size of 4k, and I was able to create a single 1 byte file, but no more than that, which is expected. I was also able to create 960k empty files, which is the default inode limit on tmpfs on my system, proving that the storage of data and metadata are separate.